# In SSMS copied string has different behaviour to original string

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am attempting to semi automate creation of my databases
As part of this I want to add extended properties of column descriptions. 
When I try to run sp_sqlexec in my script ( or even just Exec(@mystring) I get an error. However, if while debugging, I copy the dynamic sql string from the watch window and then run sp_sqlexec on the copied string in a seperate window I get no errors and the extended properties are added correctly. 
The following script demonstrates the problem:

```
--Create a table to apply column descriptions to 

Create table dbo.table1 (id int, name nvarchar(20));

--Create the table that contains our column descriptions

Create table dbo.column_descs_table (schemaname nvarchar(20), tablename nvarchar(20), columnname nvarchar(20), column_description nvarchar(20))

Insert into column_descs_table (schemaname, tablename, columnname, column_description)
values ('dbo', 'table1', 'id', 'the id column'), ('dbo' , 'table1', 'name', 'the name column');

--Dynamic sql string varaible to hold the commands
Declare @dyn_sql nvarchar(max);
Set @dyn_sql = 'N'''; --Set to opening quote 

--now create the string containing commands to add column escriptions
SELECT @dyn_sql = @dyn_sql + N' EXEC sp_addextendedproperty ''''Col Desc'''', ''''' + column_description + N''''', ''''SCHEMA'''', ' + schemaname +  N', ''''TABLE'''', ' + tablename + N', ''''COLUMN'''', ' + columnname + N' ;'   
FROM dbo.column_descs_table

Set @dyn_sql = @dyn_sql + ''''; --add the closing quote

Print @dyn_sql --If I copy the contents of @dyn_sql here and run seperately it works OK

Exec sp_sqlexec @dyn_sql -- this line causes error
```

The error I get is 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ' EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 'Col Desc', 'the id column', 'SCHEMA', dbo, 'TABLE', table1, 'COLUMN', id ; EXEC sp_addextendedprope'.

Yet if I step through the code and copy the contents of @dyn_sql then paste this as follows:

Exec sp_sqlexec N' EXEC sp_addextendedproperty ''Col Desc'', ''the id column'', ''SCHEMA'', dbo, ''TABLE'', table1, ''COLUMN'', id ; EXEC sp_addextendedproperty ''Col Desc'', ''the name column'', ''SCHEMA'', dbo, ''TABLE'', table1, ''COLUMN'', name ;'

Then the above works fine and the column descriptions are added as expected.

Any help on this specific copying problem is much appreciated. I do understand the security issues with dynamic sql ( this script will be removed from the database once my setup is complete)

Thanks in advance

Jude

Comment: sp_sqlexec was supposedly removed in SQL Server 7 and no longer officially supported (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917540.aspx). I'm surprised it's still present in SQL2008R2 - online documentation on it is long gone.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will be changing my scripts to use sp_executesql.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's because your leading N is included *within* the string to execute; you don't need it at all. In other words, you are ending up with something like this:

`exec sp_execsql 'N'' exec sp_addextendedproperty /* etc. */ '''`

But it should be like this:

`exec sp_execsql N'exec sp_addextendedproperty /* etc. */ '`

But why are you even using dynamic SQL here? All values passed to sp_addextendedproperty can be [passed as parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180047%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) so there is no obvious reason to use dynamic SQL, unless you've simplified something for the question.

Finally, you should be using sp_executesql, it's the [preferred way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178115%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to execute dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thank you. I have now tried removing the Ns and changing sp_sqlexec to sp_executesql. Sadly I am still getting the same problem. The advice on changing to sp_executesql was very useful though I will change my original script to use this (the script here is a simplified version of it) and see if I can get rid of some ofthe dynamic sql. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Yes, you should definitely use sp_executesql because you can pass parameters into it, so that should remove any issues with quoting and building the string.

Comment: I have solved my string copying problem. SQL was removing some double quotes that it deemed surplus. This is a simple example showing the problem and solution:

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have resolved my string copying problem. SQL was detecting double quotes in by concatenated string as empty strings and removing them. A simple example showing the problem and my solution is below:

```
--Example to Select 'simple string' and then 'concat string' into results sets
DECLARE
   @Simplestring nvarchar( max ) = '' , 
   @Concatstring nvarchar( max ) = '' ,
   @Stringvar nvarchar( 10 ) = 'string';

--The double quotes in next line are the quotemark we want plus a quotemark acting 
--as an escape character
--@simplestring will be set to 'Select 'simple string' '
SET @Simplestring = 'Select ''simple string'' ';

--Similarly we need @concatstring to be set to 'Select 'Concat string' '
SET @Concatstring = 'Select  '' concat' + @Stringvar + ''; -- this wont work the last 
--double quote will be removed

--Add a character that cannot appear in any othe part of the concatenation - I've used *
SET @Concatstring = 'Select '' Concat ' + @Stringvar + '*';
--Now replace the * with a quote mark
SET @Concatstring = REPLACE( @Concatstring , '*' , '''' ); -- This will work

EXEC sp_executesql @Simplestring;  
EXEC sp_executesql @Concatstring;
```

There may be a simpler solution than mine.

Many thanks for the advice on using sp_executesql. I am working on changing my code to use this ( with variables passed in as parametrs).

Jude